# Passing data from fragment to another fragment. Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I got a problem in passing data from fragment to another fragment.

Error :

> > Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentBayar{5cd96b2} not attached to a context.
> >             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:614)
> >             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:678)
> >             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:700)
> >             at com.kensai.appkasir.fragment.FragmentBayar$Companion.newInstance(FragmentBayar.kt:45)
> >             at com.kensai.appkasir.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.kt:55)
> >             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
> >             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)

Here my Fragment

```
class FragmentBayar : Fragment(){
// order information
private lateinit var order: Orders

// data of menu before send
private var editList = ArrayList<EditQuantity>()
private lateinit var dataEditAdapter: EditQuantityAdapter

// data of menu after send
private var progressList = ArrayList<ProgressAntar>()
private lateinit var dataProgressAdapter: ProgressAntarAdapter

companion object {
    fun newInstance(order: Orders): FragmentBayar {
        val fragment = FragmentBayar()

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(fragment.getString(R.string.key_pass_order), order)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}

// update array list of edit menu from clicked menu fragment
fun updateOrderEditList(menu: Menu){
    val editMenu = EditQuantity(menu,1,"")
    editList.add(0,editMenu)
    rec_edit_quantity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

// read argumen as order object
private fun readBundle(bundle: Bundle?) {
    if (bundle != null) {
        order = bundle.getParcelable(getString(R.string.key_pass_order))
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bayar, container, false)

    // get order
    readBundle(arguments)

    // change name order in header of view
    view.order_name.text = order.order

    // initial recyclerview edit item
    view.rec_edit_quantity.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    view.rec_edit_quantity.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
    view.rec_edit_quantity.hasFixedSize()
    view.rec_edit_quantity.adapter = EditQuantityAdapter(editList){ editPosition: Int -> editItemClicked(editPosition) }
    // initial recyclerview edit item data
    dataEditAdapter = EditQuantityAdapter(editList){ editPosition: Int -> editItemClicked(editPosition) }
    view.rec_edit_quantity.adapter = dataEditAdapter

    // initial recyclerview progress item
    view.rec_progress_antar.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    view.rec_progress_antar.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
    view.rec_progress_antar.hasFixedSize()
    view.rec_progress_antar.adapter = ProgressAntarAdapter(progressList)
    // initial recyclerview progress item data
    dataProgressAdapter = ProgressAntarAdapter(progressList)
    view.rec_progress_antar.adapter = dataProgressAdapter

    // setup pesan button
    btn_pesan.setOnClickListener {
        sendOrder()
    }

    // get detail service from server
    getOrderDetailService()

    return view
}

// call to get order detail from web service
private fun getOrderDetailService() {
    //temp
    progressList = getOrderData()
    dataProgressAdapter.updateData(progressList)
}

// send order list to server
private fun sendOrder(){
    val apiService : Service = Client.getClient()!!.create(Service::class.java)
    apiService.sendOrder(editList).enqueue(object : Callback<List<ProgressAntar>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ProgressAntar>>?, response: Response<List<ProgressAntar>>?) {
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful) {
                val list = response.body()

                if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Tidak ada daftar pembayaran", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else{
                    // empty edit list
                    editList = ArrayList()
                    dataEditAdapter.updateData(editList)
                    // refresh progress list
                    progressList = ArrayList(list)
                    dataProgressAdapter.updateData(progressList)
                }

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Tidak ada daftar pembayaran", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ProgressAntar>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.i("onFailure", t.toString())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}

// delete menu item before send
private fun editItemClicked(menuItem : Int){
    editList.removeAt(menuItem)
    rec_edit_quantity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

// temp function
private fun getOrderData(): ArrayList<ProgressAntar>{
    val list = ArrayList<ProgressAntar>()
    list.add(ProgressAntar("1","Bakso",15000, 4,0,false))
    list.add(ProgressAntar("2","Teh Panas",  15000, 3,0, false))
    list.add(ProgressAntar("3","Mie Aceh",  15000, 5,5, true))
    list.add(ProgressAntar("4","Teh Dingin",  15000, 3,3, true))

    return list
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    getOrderDetailService()
}
```

}

This is the Activity Class

```
class FragmentActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FragmentKategori.OnItemSelectedListener,
    FragmentMenu.OnItemSelectedListener {

// current order information
private lateinit var order: Orders

// action for item clicked on category fragment
override fun onCategoryItemSelected(category: Category) {
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.placeholder2) as FragmentMenu
    fragment.updateMenuList(category)
}

// action for item clicked on menu fragment
override fun onMenuItemSelected(menu: Menu) {
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.placeholder3) as FragmentBayar
    fragment.updateOrderEditList(menu)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_fragment)
    requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    // get bundle from previous activity
    val bundle = this.intent.extras

    // get order
    if(bundle.containsKey(getString(R.string.passOrder))){
        order = bundle.getParcelable(getString(R.string.passOrder))

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        finish()
    }

    val fragment1 = FragmentKategori()
    val fragment2 = FragmentMenu()
    val fragment3 = FragmentBayar.newInstance(order)

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.placeholder1,fragment1)
            .replace(R.id.placeholder2,fragment2)
            .replace(R.id.placeholder3,fragment3)
            .commit()
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: android.view.Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search,menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    val id = item?.itemId

    if (id == R.id.search){
        swipeView()
    }else if (id == android.R.id.home){
        finish()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

// change view to search
private fun swipeView(){
    // show search view
    if (rec_menu.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
        rec_menu.visibility = View.GONE
        lay_search.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    // show menu view
    else{
        rec_menu.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        lay_search.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by your trace, the problem is in:

```
fun newInstance(order: Orders): FragmentBayar {
    val fragment = FragmentBayar()

    val bundle = Bundle()
    /* here --> */bundle.putParcelable(fragment.getString(R.string.key_pass_order), order)
    fragment.arguments = bundle
    return fragment
}
```

when you call `fragment.getString(R.string.key_pass_order)`, you need the fragment to be attached to an activity in order to get the context. As you just initialized the fragment, there is no context associated with.

Anyway, the usual practice to put extras in a bundle is to declare constants to write/read its properties. A brief explanation is because you don't need it to be exposed and they can be private to the class' scope.

**Example:**

```
companion object {
    private const val KEY_PASS_ORDER = "KEY_PASS_ORDER"

    fun newInstance(order: Orders): FragmentBayar {
        val fragment = FragmentBayar()

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(KEY_PASS_ORDER, order)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}

private fun readBundle(bundle: Bundle?) {
    if (bundle != null) {
        order = bundle.getParcelable(KEY_PASS_ORDER)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //------------------pass data one fragment to another fragment ------------
    First fragment

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

        SendMessage SM;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
            return rootView;


        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            Button btnPassData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPassData);
            final EditText inData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inMessage);
            btnPassData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SM.sendData(inData.getText().toString().trim());
                }
            });

        }

        interface SendMessage {
            void sendData(String message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);

            try {
                SM = (SendMessage) getActivity();
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException("Error in retrieving data. Please try again");
            }
        }
    }

    //------------------second fragment----------------------------



    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

        TextView txtData;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            txtData = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtData);
        }

        protected void displayReceivedData(String message


)
        {
            txtData.setText("Data received: "+message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i face this problem before and solve it from Android Developer website from this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

It's important to build an interface so the fragments can communicate between each others through their activity